# Divisor is equal to zero in my query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Thanks for reading my question.

I have the below query.

```
   round(count(product)*100/(select sum(count(product)) FROM FACTORY 
   WHERE TRUNC(COMPLETED) >= '01-MAR-2013' and 
   TRUNC(COMPLETED) <= '31-MAR-2013' 
   group by (product))) as percentage FROM FACTORY
```

I get the below error.

```
    Error: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
    SQLState:  22012
    ErrorCode: 1476
```

I tried to put COALESCE but still getting the same error.

```
  round(count(product)*100/(select COALESCE(sum(count(product)),0) FROM FACTORY 
  WHERE TRUNC(COMPLETED) >= '01-MAR-2013' and 
  TRUNC(COMPLETED) <= '31-MAR-2013' 
  group by (product))) as percentage FROM FACTORY
```

Kindly help.

Comment: How is attempting to replace 0 with 0 supposed to help? I don't follow your logic. And what's the expected outcome if that sum is zero?

Comment: I guess anything other than zero would do. Plz help. I tried with 1 but doesn't help

Comment: Only you can tell us what you want to happen when the sum is zero. If you explain that, maybe someone can tell you how to make it happen.

Comment: Can I run this query without the error?

Comment: Filter out data in using a where clause so that you don't get 0 values. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: This query confuses me. What's the point of doing the `group by product` and counting the number of rows in each group, if you're just going to sum the counts? Isn't that the same as doing one count without a `group by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out data in using a where clause so that you don't get 0 values. I have added product !=0 in where clause

Answer (score 2):

try

1)

```
SELECT  xxx/ NULLIF(yyyy,0) FROM [dbo].[tablename]
```

or

2)

```
SELECT  COALESCE(xxx / NULLIF(yyyy,0), 0) FROM [dbo].[tablename]
```

Comment: The 2nd would error out, as the COALESCE negates the NULLIF and results in dividing my zero.

Comment: +1  @GoatCO It should work.  For example: `SELECT COALESCE(100 / NULLIF(0,0), 0) FROM dual;` returns 0.

Comment: I added Filter out data in using a where clause so that you don't get 0 values. Thanks guys

Comment: Brief explanation of the solution.Any Number divided by NULL returns NULL in Oracle. NULLIF function compares expr1 and expr2,If they are equal it returns NULL else it returns expr1. COALESCE returns the first non-null operand in the argument list.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14300/0